# Bash - Search and Replace operation with reporting the files and lines that got changed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find

I have a input file "test.txt" as below -

```
hostname=abc.com hostname=xyz.com
db-host=abc.com db-host=xyz.com
```

In each line, the value before space is the old value which needs to be replaced by the new value after the space recursively in a folder named "test". I am able to do this using below shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' 
for f in `cat test.txt`
do
  OLD=$(echo $f| cut -d ' ' -f 1) 
  echo "Old = $OLD"
  NEW=$(echo $f| cut -d ' ' -f 2)
  echo "New = $NEW"
  find test -type f | xargs sed -i.bak "s/$OLD/$NEW/g"
done
```

"sed" replaces the strings on the fly in 100s of files.

Is there a trick or an alternative way by which i can get a report of the files changed like absolute path of the file & the exact lines that got changed ?

PS - I understand that sed or stream editors doesn't support this functionality out of the box. I don't want to use versioning as it will be an overkill for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a simple rewrite of your script, to make it a little bit more robust at handling a wider range of replacement values, but also faster:

```
#!/bin/bash

# escape regexp and replacement strings for sed
escapeRegex() { sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$1"; }
escapeSubst() { sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"$1"; }

while read -r old new; do
    find test -type f -exec sed "/$(escapeRegex "$old")/$(escapeSubst "$new")/g" -i '{}' \;
done <test.txt
```

So, we loop over pairs of whitespace-separated fields (`old`, `new`) in lines from `test.txt` and run a standard `sed` in-place replace on all files found with `find`.

Pretty similar to your script, but we [properly read lines](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) from `test.txt` (no word splitting, pathname/variable expansion, etc.), we use Bash builtins whenever possible (no need to call external tools like `cat`, `cut`, `xargs`); and we [escape `sed` metacharacters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) in `old`/`new` values for proper use as `sed`'s regexp and replacement expressions.

Now let's add [logging from sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97297/how-to-report-sed-in-place-changes):

```
#!/bin/bash

# escape regexp and replacement strings for sed
escapeRegex() { sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$1"; }
escapeSubst() { sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"$1"; }

while read -r old new; do
    find test -type f -printf '\n[%p]\n' -exec sed "/$(escapeRegex "$old")/{
        h
        s//$(escapeSubst "$new")/g
        H
        x
        s/\n/ --> /
        w /dev/stdout
        x
    }" -i '{}' > >(tee -a change.log) \;
done <test.txt
```

The `sed` script above changes each `old` to `new`, but it also writes `old --> new` line to `/dev/stdout` (Bash-specific), which we in turn append to `change.log` file. The `-printf` action in `find` outputs a "header" line with file name, for each file processed.

With this, your "change log" will look something like:

```
[file1]
hostname=abc.com --> hostname=xyz.com

[file2]

[file1]
db-host=abc.com --> db-host=xyz.com

[file2]
db-host=abc.com --> db-host=xyz.com
```

Just for completeness, a quick walk-through the `sed` script. We act only on lines containing the `old` value. For each such line, we store it to hold space (`h`), change it to `new`, append that new value to the hold space (joined with newline, `H`) which now holds `old\nnew`. We swap hold with pattern space (`x`), so we can run `s` command that converts it to `old --> new`. After writing that to the `stdout` with `w`, we move the `new` back from hold to pattern space, so it gets written (in-place) to the file processed.

Answer (score 2):

From `man sed`:

> ```
>    -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>           edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
> ```

This can be used to create a backup file when replacing. You can then look for any backup files, which indicate which files were changed, and `diff` those with the originals. Once you're done inspecting the diff, simply remove the backup files.

If you formulate your replacements as `sed` statements rather than a custom format you can go one further, and use either a `sed` shebang line or pass the file to `-f/--file` to do all the replacements in one operation.

Comment: Nice idea, I had thought of it but it becomes complex to manage when there are multiple changes in a single file. "sed" creates numerous files with mulitple ".bak" extention like 1.bak.bak.bak .

Answer (score 0):

There's several problems with your script, just replace it all with (using GNU awk instead of GNU sed for inplace editing):

```
mapfile -t files < <(find test -type f)
awk -i inplace '
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
{ for (old in map) gsub(old,map[old]) }
' test.txt "${files[@]}"
```

You'll find that is orders of magnitude faster than what you were doing.

That still has the issue your existing script does of failing when the "test.txt" strings contain regexp or backreference metacharacters and modifying previously-modified strings and handling partial matches - if that's an issue let us know as it's easy to work around with awk (and extremely difficult with sed!).

To get whatever kind of report you want you just tweak the `{ for ... }` line to print them, e.g. to print a record of the changes to stderr:

```
mapfile -t files < <(find test -type f)
awk -i inplace '
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
{
    orig = $0
    for (old in map) {
        gsub(old,map[old])
    }
    if ($0 != orig) {
        printf "File %s, line %d: \"%s\" became \"%s\"\n", FILENAME, FNR, orig, $0 | "cat>&2"
    }
}
' test.txt "${files[@]}"
```