# sed replace using string containing backslashes

Tags: sed, escaping, cygwin

I need to replace text in a file with a Windows-style directory path containing backslash (REVERSE SOLIDUS) characters. I am already using an alternative expression delimiter. The backslashes appear to be treated as escape characters.

How can I keep the backslashes in the output?

```
$ echo DIR=foobar | sed -e "s#DIR=.*#$(cygpath -w $(pwd))#"
C:gwin64homelit
```

The desired output is:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\lit
```

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed ... or if you have `perl`, save the result in variable, for ex: `a=$(cygpath -w $(pwd))` and try `perl -pe "s#DIR=.*#q($a)#e"` or if `PWD` env variable works:  `perl -pe "s#DIR=.*#q($PWD)#e"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to escape metacharacters in `sed` replacement pattern. Fortunately, there are only three of those: `&`, `\`, and a delimiter `/` (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/232065) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/404556)). In your case, since you're using `#` for delimiter, you'll have to escape `#` instead of `/`.

You can create a helper shell function (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44863324/404556)):

```
escapeSubst() { sed 's/[&#\]/\\&/g'; }
```

and then pass your string through it before giving it to `sed`, like this:

```
$ echo DIR=foobar | sed -e "s#DIR=.*#$(cygpath -w $(pwd) | escapeSubst)#"
C:\cygwin64\home\lit
```

Comment: The link Sundeep provided also led to this.

Comment: Yes, the question about escaping variable pattern/replacement string for `sed` has been answered there.